# How to implement a HTTP PATCH call using RestEasy

Tags: java, resteasy

Using RestEasy (3.0.10.Final) I want to know how I have to transform the next stuff to do a PATCH call instead of a POST one:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

...

ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url);
javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> entidad = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(jsonEnviar, "application/json");
Response responseWs = target.request().post(entidad);
```

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Comment: 3.0.10.Final (edited main post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://www.google.com");
            javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> entidad = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(test, "application/json");
            Response responseWs = target.request().method("PATCH",entidad);
```

this seems to be working. Not sure if I am missing anything here.

[image]